# запятые, тире

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли таким образом поставить пунктуационные знаки: «это допускает перенос понятия на законодательную, а точнее — на правотворческую, правоустановительную — практику без терминологической корректировки»?

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Для обособления с помощью тире фрагмента "на правотворческую, правоустановительную"  нет никаких оснований. Запятая после "точнее" тоже весьма сомнительна.
Можно так:
*Это допускает перенос понятия на законодательную (а точнее — на правотворческую, правоустановительную) практику без терминологической корректировки.*
Или в крайнем случае так:
*Это допускает перенос понятия на законодательную — а точнее: на правотворческую, правоустановительную - практику без терминологической корректировки.*

Но вообще-то фразу стоит немного перестроить. Хотя бы в части "на правотворческую и правоустановительную".

Answer (score 0):

«Это допускает перенос понятия на законодательную, а точнее, на правотворческую, правоустановительную  практику без терминологической корректировки».

Answer (score 0):

Тире не нужно, вводное слово точнее с союзом а выделяется запятыми, потому что можно добавить слово "говоря" (точнее говоря). Но не двоеточине, как предлагают. Запятая после "а точнее" возможна в зависимости от вкладываемого смысла. См. Розеталя.

Comment: Что именно надо посмотреть у Розенталя? 
Особенно в плане обоснования обособления "а точнее" **потому, что** можно вставить слово.  
И почему не двоеточие? Это действительно было бы "авторской" пунктуацией, но не противоречащей, имхо, никаким никаным правилам, последующая часть раскрывает смысл "точнее".  
И наконец, какое из двух авторских тире вы сочли "не нужным"?

Comment: Здравствуйте!)
Не могу дать вам ссылку в нете, потому что у меня справочник Розенталя в обычном, книжном варианте) (Д. Э. Розенталь. Справочник по пунктуации. Для работников печати). Это пар. 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания. п. 5. Примечания. Тут именно про пунктуацию со словом ТОЧНЕЕ. 
Согласна с вами в том, что в данном примере двоеточие возможно только как авторская пунктуация.
Не сердитесь, behemothus, (впрочем, я думаю, вы и не сердитесь) у вас замечательные, всегда грамотные и интересные комментарии!))

Comment: А про тире как авторский знак... По большому счету, его можно поставить везде, где автор пожелает, даже вместо двоеточия. Тот же Розенталь приводит массу примеров использования тире вместо двоеточия.

Comment: Это он?
http://bookfi.org/book/384801?_ir=1

Comment: «Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация»: Оникс 21 век, Мир и Образование; 2002 ISBN 5 329 00324 5  
РАЗДЕЛ 7 Знаки препинания при словах, грамматически не связанных с членами предложения  
§ 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания  
~5 Вводные слова отделяются от предшествующего сочинительного союза запятой, если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры...  

Никаких примечаний нет, упоминаний слова "точнее" тоже пока не вижу.

Comment: Авторской я называю пунктуцию, которая в принципе соответствует правилам, но не совсем обычна. Т.е. в данном случае акцентирует внимание на перечисление. Смысл был именно в этом.  

ЗЫ Разумеется, я не сержусь. Скорее радуюсь, что есть о чем поспорить.

Comment: Нашел. В другом месте это п. 1.4)

Слова вернее, *точнее*, скорее  являются вводными, если после них можно добавить слово говоря  (см. § 22, п. 4, прим. 2): Мы познакомились с соседями или, вернее, с соседками  (Кав.); Я присмотрелся, попривык к окружающим меня явлениям или, вернее сказать, чудесам природы  (Акс.); Я, собственно, ничем не болен  (Вер.) («собственно говоря»; ср.: А ты кто такой, собственно?); Его выдержка, точнее, его хладнокровие всегда выручает его;

Comment: Рада, что мы все разобрались))